# How to override File::Copy::move?

Tags: perl, overriding

Consider the following simple module MyCode.pm. It contains a single function `my_function` touching a file and then renaming it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyCode;

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::File;
use File::Copy;

sub my_function {
  # touch /tmp/a
  my $fh = IO::File->new();
  $fh->open(">/tmp/a") || die "open failed ($!)";  
  $fh->close() || die "close failed ($!)";
  unlink("/tmp/aa"); # ignore errors; we want file removed
  move("/tmp/a", "/tmp/aa") || die "move failed ($!)";
}

1;
```

Now consider the following test program. It will successfully override `IO::File::open`, `IO::File::close` but not `File::Copy::move`. Why?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::File;
use File::Copy;

use MyCode;

{
  no warnings 'redefine';
  local *IO::File::open = sub  { 
    eval {      
      $! = 44; # random value for illustration purposes
      die;
    };
  };

  eval {
    MyCode::my_function() 
  };
  print $@ if $@;
}

{
  no warnings 'redefine';
  local *IO::File::close = sub {
    eval {
      $! = 33; # random value for illustration purposes
      die;
    };
  };

  eval {
    MyCode::my_function() 
  };
  print $@ if $@;
}

{
  no warnings 'redefine';
  local *File::Copy::move = sub {
    eval {
      $! = 22; # random value for illustration purposes
      die;
    };
  };

  eval {
    MyCode::my_function() 
  };
  print $@ if $@;
}
```

Program output below. There is no output for the `move` override, which means it does not kick in. Why? I'd like to know also why I am getting that warning.

```
Name "IO::File::close" used only once: possible typo at ./test.pl line 28.
open failed (Channel number out of range) at MyCode.pm line 14.

close failed (Numerical argument out of domain) at MyCode.pm line 15.
```

Comment: not clear what the failing code actually looks like; can you post the relevant parts of MyCode.pm and your test script?

Comment: I rewrote my question from scratch with a complete demo of my problem.

Comment: Why not use [`Sub::Override`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Override) ?

Comment: I have constraints on the modules and Perl version I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It will successfully override IO::File::open, IO::File::close but not File::Copy::move. Why?*

It does override `File::Copy::move`. The issue is that you don't call `File::Copy::move`, but `MyCode::move`. As such, you need to use

```
local *MyCode::move = sub { ... };
```

---

> *I'd like to know also why I am getting [the warning `Name "IO::File::close" used only once: possible typo`].*

The warning exists to help find typos. It's emitted when package symbols are only encountered once during the compilation. In this case, it's a spurious warning (just like the redefined warnings you disabled).

Replace

```
no warnings 'redefine';
```

with

```
no warnings 'once';
```

Comment: Update my answer for the change to the question.

Comment: the warning is only semi-spurious; there exists an IO::File::open but no IO::File::close; IO::File inherits close from IO::Handle.

Comment: Looks like I should be reading on namespaces. Is it correct to say the call to `move` from MyCode creates an alias `MyCode::move` pointing to `File::Copy::move`?

Comment: @ysth, This instance is safe to ignore, so by definition it's spurious. No idea what you mean by semi-spurious or what distinction you are trying to make.

Comment: @Philippe A., No. `use File::Copy;` calls File::Copy's `import`, which copies `&File::Copy::move` (meaning the subroutine named associated with symbol `File::Copy::move`) into `&MySub::move`, and `move()` is short for `MySub::move()`.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of full path (File::Copy::move) works perfectly fine. Just need to change 'use' to 'require' to import at runtime.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# use File::Copy;
require File::Copy;
use Errno;

{
  no warnings 'redefine';
  local *move = sub { 
    eval {      
      $! = Errno::EREMMO;
      die "oops ($!)";
    };
  };

File::Copy::move("d:\\swadhi\\perl\\a.txt.bak", "D:\\swadhi\\perl\\bakkkkkup.txt") || print $@;
```

Comment: *need not change use to require unless you want to import File::Copy::move at runtime. Cheers!

Comment: That "solution" breaks the code that did work, and does nothing to address the code that didn't work. This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: No, the issue isn't that I don't understand your answer; it's that you don't understand the question. It has been updated to be clearer, so have another read.